# Горизонтальный скроллинг. Выбор месяца.

Tags: android, java, calendar

Здравствуйте!
Пытаюсь реализовать горизонтальный скроллинг месяцев. Наткнулся на [вот на что](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging--mobile-8231).
Все бы хорошо, но на экране я могу увидеть только 1 layout, соответственно, название только одного месяца. А мне нужно видеть не только текущий, но и те которые рядом.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо гуглить вот это:

> [viewpager show multiple pages](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=viewpager%20show%20multiple%20pages)

По [первой ссылке в выдаче](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836323/multiple-pages-at-the-same-time-on-a-viewpager) есть вопрос, [второй ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21239185/3212712), к коему выдаёт ссыль на GitHub, где есть то, что вам нужно, а именно [имплементация ViewPager](https://github.com/Pixplicity/MultiViewPager), позволяющая показывать несколько фрагментов одновременно.

Answer (score 1):

Можно fragment маленькие создать и пролистывать их, или listView горизонтально с анимацией...